# Error compiling [make] Mosquitto 1.4.8

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, mqtt, iot, mosquitto

I want to install MQTT server on Ubuntu.

I'm following: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-setup-a-mosquitto-mqtt-server-and-receive-data-from-owntracks

I'm at Step 2: Install Mosquitto.
A problem occurs when I input `commands >>> make`...

[image: Console Image]

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are missing the compiler.  install it with the following command:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

This is mentioned in step 2 of the instructions in your link:

`apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential libwrap0-dev libssl-dev libc-ares-dev uuid-dev xsltproc`

You will likely need to precede both of the above commands with `sudo`